# Well breaker tripped we ant reset it

Tags: well-pump

I was in the shower and water just shut off. The breaker tripped we tried resetting it all it does is hum then its off again. We have no water. What can we do

Comment: Sounds like the well pump has died.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the humming sound is your well pump (were you able to hear it when it was working?) then it either has something stuck inside or it has simply seized up.

If you cannot normally hear the well pump, and the humming sound comes from the breaker itself, that means it's definitely seized and is drawing a LOT of power until the breaker trips. Stop doing that.

Either way, time for a new pump.

Changing a well pump is one of those things where if you have to ask how, you need to call someone. Electricity and water don't get along very much and mistakes can be costly. Like ruining the new pump and having to buy a third one, causing the well sides to collapse and therefore needing to re-dig the hole, or someone getting electrocuted and dying.

Any plumber in your area will know exactly what you need, and will likely be able to fix it the same day.

Comment: Any plumber? I rather  doubt that. Would be better to say "Find a plumber that specializes in wells and water pumps...".

Comment: @MichaelKaras I think he means "any plumber in an area where lots and lots of people have wells, because it's a big part of what they deal with day by day, especially because lots of homeowners in well country can solder a pipe themsleves".   If you are one of the 6 houses in the county of San Francisco who were somehow omitted from the City of San Francisco, you might have trouble finding a local well expert.